# Why does my window scroll event cause scrolling to break?

Tags: javascript

I apply a class when you scroll, but for some reason my scroll wheel on my mouse stops working sometimes. It seems to be at random places of the site and at random times. I can not figure out why it's behaving like that.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1) {
        if(!$(".navigation").hasClass("js-boxShadow")) {
            $(".navigation").addClass("js-boxShadow");
        }
    } else {
        $(".navigation").removeClass("js-boxShadow");
    }
});
```

I have never and I do not have this issue on any other site. I have also tried other mouses I have available and they all behave the same. So I can exclude hardware issues.

CSS:

```
.js-boxShadow {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

If I remove the `hasClass` and `addClass`, the behaviour ceases. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What does the class `js-boxShadow` do?  What styling does it apply?

Comment: Question updated with CSS.

Comment: What happens if you change the `.scrollTop()` to let's say `>= 100`

Comment: The problem still persists. I assume it's because it has to check for a class everytime you scroll, for every pixel, but I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: First thing that I would try is making the scroll event [passive](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners) then I would also [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) the callback.  See if that improves anything.

Comment: Yes, that was also my first thought, you need `debounce`.

Comment: Debouncing worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You could test your theory of the slowness being caused by the class check. Make a state variable outside your event handler and update (say, set it to true) once your `scrollTop()` condition is met. In the `else`, set it to false. Then in your class check do `if( stateVar && $(this).scrollTop() >= 1 )`. It should stop reading the condition if the first member of an && condition is false.

Comment: After some more testing, debouncing does not seem to solve it completely - only making it more rare to occur. I will try that @Drumline18

Comment: @Drumline18 That seemed to fix it! If you post that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: After trying to write what I said to do I feel like what I said was far from what I meant haha.

Comment: Yes what I wrote was wrong, please make sure your feature works right. You can disable the class check by simply removing it. `addClass` is already doing that check.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.